# Simplest way to add user authentication?

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, basic-authentication

I need to authorize access to certain parts of a very small, entirely static website. I am very resistant to the idea of using Wordpress just to do this, because it will add a whole bunch of unnecessary complexity. My goals are to simply:

1. use Google/Facebook to authenticate users
2. after authentication, use Google/Facebook APIs to authorize certain users to access a protected section

What would be the absolute simplest approach to doing this?

Thanks

Comment: From what I gather you need a login with FB/ gmail. Follow this link... https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ and choose javascript option.

Comment: But how do I block non-authenticated users from accessing a resource? I.e. how do I protect content with an FB/Google login?